# How to Change AudioMixer source at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a music application.

I would like to be able to change within the AudioMixer between different sound groups using the same GameObject.

Is it possible to change the PianoMixer source with another script at runtime?

```
public class PianoAudioManager : MonoBehaviour{

public PianoSound[] PianoSounds;
public static PianoAudioManager instance;
public AudioMixerGroup PianoMixer; 

void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = this;
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    foreach(PianoSound s in PianoSounds)
    {
        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.outputAudioMixerGroup = PianoMixer;
        s.source.clip = s.clip;

        s.source.volume = s.volume;
        s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
    }

}
```

}

I tried something like this, but I always get errors

```
public class Octaves : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject PianoAudioManager;

public void OctaveDown()
{

    AudioMixer audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Scales/Sounds");

    AudioMixerGroup[] audioMixGroup = audioMixer.FindMatchingGroups("Master/PianoDown");

    PianoAudioManager.outputAudioMixerGroup = audioMixGroup[0];
}

}
```

I would be very grateful for any help, thank you very much.

Comment: Well without knowing more (see the whole [mcve] explination) I'll confirm you can change/add/remove pretty much anything and everything at runtime. So, its possible, but from the info given its hard to advise.  You can have multiple audio sources which may solve it, you can change the mixer group, you could add audio sources... remove them...

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the answer.
Right click on the parameter name "Pitch" and choose "Expose 'Pitch' to script".

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class Octavas : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject PianoAudioManager;


public void OctaveDown()
{
    AudioMixer audioMixer = Resources.Load<AudioMixer>("Scales/Sounds");
    audioMixer.SetFloat("PianoPitch", 0.5f);
}

}
```